# Clone custom options

Tags: custom-options, products-management, ce-1.8.1.0

Is there a way to "clone" custom options from a product to other products? I need to clone a set of custom options from one product to a bunch of products.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to copy custom options from one product to another in a default Magento setup. However, you can duplicate product by using "Duplicate" button in product edit form and this should result in having duplicated product with Custom Options preserved.

If you need to have real possibility to apply the same Custom Options set to multiple products in convenient way, you may need to use a custom extension for that. [Aitoc Custom Option Templates](http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_custom_options_templates.html) may be good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used [Magmi](http://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-documentation/) CSV importer? It allows columns for [Custom Options](http://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-custom-options/). With a proper spreadsheet program you can create a formula to selectively include the custom option data as needed. For example if all shirts come in three sizes, you can use the header of

`Product Size:radio:1:1` with the data

```
=IF(SEARCH("shirt", [product_name_column]), "Small|Medium|Large", "")
```

When you export the spreadsheet to a CSV it would be set up exactly as you need it.

For your needs described above, you should be fine with 2+ columns, `sku` and your custom options. Copy your IF formula to all the rows, save as CSV, import with magmi,  and voila!